# Reading from Methods

Tags: c#

I am new and I am learning to use methods and such and I have my code in the method but in that code there is a Console.ReadLine(); which I don't want. Basically what I need to do is a big assignment with 10 methods, as input you have to call which method and then the actual input, but when there is a readline in my method I have to give 3 things instead of 2. My code is below if anyone know how to help a noob ?
 Basically the int.parse(consolereadline); I need to somehow remove it so I can only read in the Method number and then actual input.

```
 static object GetNextLeapYear(int year1)
    {
        int n, year;
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        year = n + 4 - (n % 4);
        if ((year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 != 0))
        {
            year += 4;
        }
        return year;


    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string method = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (method)
        {
            case "1":
                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                GetNextLeapYear(input);
                Console.WriteLine($"{GetNextLeapYear(input)}");
                
                break;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the ReadLine inside your method? You have already passed a _year1_ and that seems more than enough to get the remainder of a division by four.

Comment: That's how I would make it only in Main but I don't know how to put it in a Method thats my question

Comment: OK, if that is your question, why don't you explain that in your question above?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is to remove the first call to `GetNextLeapYear(input);` in the `case "1"` body. You're not storing the result of that call and you're actually displaying the result of the second call that is in the `Console.WriteLine($"{GetNextLeapYear(input)}");` which causes an additional (and unnecessary) call to Console.ReadLine in the GetNextLeapYear method.

Answer (score 0):

just remove "n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())" I don' t why do you need it at  all

```
static int GetNextLeapYear(int inputYear)
{
        var year = inputYera+ 4 - (inputYear % 4);
        if ((year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 != 0)) year += 4;   
        return year;
}
```

and code

```
Console.WriteLine("pls, type a year");
 int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var leapYear = GetNextLeapYear(input);
Console.WriteLine($"next leap year is {leapyear}");
```

but you would use something like this as a method, if it is not your high school project

```
public static int GetNextLeapYear(int year)
{
        do {

        year=year+1;

        if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)) return year;
         
    } while (true)
}
```

and added input validation in main

```
int year=0;
bool success = false;

do {
Console.WriteLine("pls, type a correct year number");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
success=int.TryParse(value, out year);
while (success);

var leapYear = GetNextLeapYear(year);
Console.WriteLine($"next leap year is {leapyear}");
```